# how do you explain the loop with a for statement?

Tags: python, loops

I have code below that basically takes a list of temperatures for each day, e.g. T = [30,50,99,44,55,33,99] and returns a list of the same length with each input indicating how many days one must wait until a warmer day occurs. So for this example, the output would be [1,1,0,1,2,1,0]. If there is no warmer day ahead, we simply insert 0.

Constraints: the length of temperatures will be in the range [1, 30000]. Each temperature will be an integer in the range [30, 100]

```
def dailyTemperatures(self, T):
        nxt = [float('inf')] * 102
        ans = [0] * len(T)
        for i in xrange(len(T) - 1, -1, -1):
            #Use 102 so min(nxt[t]) has a default value
            warmer_index = min(nxt[t] for t in xrange(T[i]+1, 102))
            if warmer_index < float('inf'):
                ans[i] = warmer_index - i
            nxt[T[i]] = i
        return ans
```

My question is for the line "warmer_index = min(nxt[t] for t in xrange(T[i]+1, 102))"; I understand it to the point where we are taking the minimum value of 102 and what? I don't get the first part of the min(). Can someone explain please?

And for the 'if statement' after it, won't this always be true, since float('inf') takes the biggest possible value?? Any explanation here would be good too thanks.

Comment: It's the minimum of all the `nxt[t]` values in the specified range.

Comment: Sorry let me add the constraints

Answer (score 1):

It's not the minimum of 102 and something.

`xrange(T[i]+1, 102)` is a sequence of integers from `T[i]+1` to `101`. These are used as the values of `t` in `nxt[t]`. `min()` then returns the minimum of all those elements of `nxt`.

```
nxt[t] for t in xrange(T[i]+1, 102)
```

is a generator expression that returns that sequence of values, and the sequence is passed to `min()` to calculate the minimum.

Regarding the `if` statement, it won't be true if no warmer days can be found, because all the `nxt` values will be `inf`. When that happens we skip the assignment to `ans[i]`, leaving the `0` value that was given initially.

Comment: Thanks so much Barmar, that's makes so much more sense now. Am I right in assuming that range() in Python 3 behaves exactly like xrange() in Python 2? Thanks

Comment: Okay great. And how about the 'if' statement to my question, won't "if warmer_index < float('inf')" always hold true in the above code? Thanks!

Comment: The initial value of `nxt` is all `inf`, so it won't hold true the first time.

Comment: Ohh I see, okay thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: Hi Barmar, sorry one last thing- I promise! I'm really trying to understand the solution but I can't seem to. here is what the solution says: "Because temperatures can only be in [30, 100], if the temperature right now is say, T[i] = 50, we only need to check for the next occurrence of 51, 52, ..., 100 and take the one that occurs soonest. (I UNDERSTAND this part)

Algorithm

Let's process each i in reverse (decreasing order). At each T[i], to know when the next occurrence of say, temperature 100 is, we should just remember the last one we've seen, next[100]. - (I DON'T UNDERSTAND)

Comment: Rather than always searching for a temperature in the list `T`, we can save its index in another list `nxt`. Searching long lists is slow, indexing is fast.